# setting conda environment installed jupyter notebook config

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am running anaconda jupyter notebook on remote ubuntu machine, and I have three separate conda environments.

```
base                  *  /home/user/anaconda3
dev                      /home/user/anaconda3/envs/dev
pytorch                  /home/user/anaconda3/envs/pytorch
```

In order to use juypter notebook remote, I am using localhost:8888 for base environment and I want to configure *pytorch* environment's default port to localhost:8889. such that

```
c.NotebookApp.port = 8889
```

But when I attempts

```
notebook --generate-config
```

command, it asks me whether to overwrite or not.

```
Overwrite /home/user/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py with default config? [y/N]
```

Is there any way that I can generate jupyter config file for *pytorch* conda environment independent from *base* conda environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably add some logic into the config (untested):

```
from os import environ
cenv = environ['CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV']
if 'pytorch' in cenv:
    c.NotebookApp.port = 8889
```

Comment: in my `environ` instance, there is no such 'CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV' key

Comment: I've found a way to register CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539623/how-do-i-find-the-name-of-the-conda-environment-in-which-my-code-is-running and will try your method

Comment: Glad I can help :)