# "which conda" command returns something not expected

Tags: python, macos, conda

When I type `which conda` in terminal it returns somewhat unexpected result as below.

```
conda () {
        if [ "$#" -ge 1 ]
        then
                local cmd="$1" 
                shift
        else
                local cmd="" 
        fi
        case "$cmd" in
                (activate) _conda_activate "$@" ;;
                (deactivate) _conda_deactivate "$@" ;;
                (install | update | uninstall | remove) $_CONDA_EXE "$cmd" "$@"
                        _conda_reactivate ;;
                (*) $_CONDA_EXE "$cmd" "$@" ;;
        esac
}
```

I'm using pyenv in MAC.

I looked `~/.zshrc` but found nothing special.

I expected which version I'm using to be printed, but I am getting some messages I cannot understand

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Executing `which -p conda` in your `zsh`, it will return the path instead of the script.
For more information, read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211246/how-do-i-find-the-actual-binary-script-using-which-in-zsh/211253#211253) answer.

Answer (score 4):

Starting version `4.4`, `conda` uses a wrapper shell function to capture commands and pass it to the executable. Not sure which version of conda you're using, and I'm more familiar of the [Bash wrapper](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/conda/shell/etc/profile.d/conda.sh) but it definitely looks like such function.

If you want to know the version, you should use `conda --version`.

Else, use `conda` or `conda --help` for more information on the CLI, or have a look to the [official doc](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: my conda is 4.4.10 and I still want to use "which conda" to figure out am I using what conda env I am using.

Comment: `which conda` will not give you the environnement you're using, but should give you the path to the conda executable. Can you try to upgrade your conda version (should be `conda update conda -n root` for 4.4). Usually there is a PS1 modifier to indicate that in your terminal, alternatively you can use `conda env list` for this. The environment with a star is the active one.

Comment: @임정섭 There is [another question that answers how to determine the active env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539623/how-do-i-find-the-name-of-the-conda-environment-in-which-my-code-is-running). To be fair, your question only asked for version, not environment, and Fabien has answered that very clearly. Please also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @nerv "echo $CONDA_PREFIX" in [another question that answers how to determine the active env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36539623/how-do-i-find-the-name-of-the-conda-environment-in-which-my-code-is-running) is helpful.

Comment: Glad it solved your issue. You're right for using `$CONDA_PREFIX`, but be careful that it is a component internal to conda, it was added in the 4.4 branch and is not guaranteed to be stable forever.