# Importing the numpy C-extensions failed for embedded Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, anaconda

I seem to have a problem importing numpy only when trying to run my C++ code with embedded Python. The following code is just a dummy code that captures the problem.

Python:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

class model:
    def init(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        
def test_method(a,b):
    m = model()
    m.init(a,b)
    print("a: ",a,"b: ",b)
    return (a+b,a-b,a*b)

def list_method(a,b):
    m = model()
    m.init(a,b)
    La = [1,2,3]
    sa = 3
    Lb = [2,3,5,7,11]
    sb = 5
    return (La,sa,Lb,sb)
```

C++:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue, *pValue_1, *pValue_2;
    double sum,diff,prod;

    double a = atof(argv[1]);
    double b = atof(argv[2]);

    int l_a,l_b;

    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; sys.path.append('/home/MyFolder')");
    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("EmbedTest");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    if(pModule != NULL) {
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule,"test_method");
    if(pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
      pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);
        pValue_1 = PyFloat_FromDouble(a);
        pValue_2 = PyFloat_FromDouble(b);
        if (!pValue_1) {
        Py_DECREF(pArgs);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
        return 1;
        }
        if (!pValue_2) {
        Py_DECREF(pArgs);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
        return 1;
        }
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue_1);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pValue_2);
        
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
            Py_DECREF(pArgs);
            if (pValue != NULL) {
        sum = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyTuple_GetItem(pValue,0));
        diff = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyTuple_GetItem(pValue,1));
        prod = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyTuple_GetItem(pValue,2));
                printf("a: %f b: %f sum: %f diff: %f prod: %f \n",a,b,sum,diff,
               prod);
                Py_DECREF(pValue);
            }
            else {
                Py_DECREF(pFunc);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                PyErr_Print();
                fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
    } else {
            if (PyErr_Occurred())
                PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
        }
        Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule,"list_method");
    if(pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
        pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);
        pValue_1 = PyFloat_FromDouble(a);
        pValue_2 = PyFloat_FromDouble(b);
        if (!pValue_1) {
        Py_DECREF(pArgs);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
        return 1;
        }
        if (!pValue_2) {
        Py_DECREF(pArgs);
        Py_DECREF(pModule);
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot convert argument\n");
        return 1;
        }
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue_1);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pValue_2);
        
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
            Py_DECREF(pArgs);
            if (pValue != NULL) {
        pValue_1 = PyTuple_GetItem(pValue,0);
        l_a = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyTuple_GetItem(pValue,1));
        pValue_2 = PyTuple_GetItem(pValue,2);
        l_b = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyTuple_GetItem(pValue,3));
        if(pValue_1 != NULL && pValue_2 != NULL) {
            for(int i = 0; i < l_a; i++) {
            printf("La[%d]: %f\n",i,
                   PyFloat_AsDouble(PyList_GetItem(pValue_1,i)));
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < l_b; i++) {
            printf("Lb[%d]: %f\n",i,
                   PyFloat_AsDouble(PyList_GetItem(pValue_2,i)));
            }
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr,"NEEE!\n");
        }
                Py_DECREF(pValue);
            }
            else {
                Py_DECREF(pFunc);
                Py_DECREF(pModule);
                PyErr_Print();
                fprintf(stderr,"Call failed\n");
                return 1;
            }
    } else {
            if (PyErr_Occurred())
                PyErr_Print();
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot find function \"%s\"\n", argv[2]);
        }
        Py_XDECREF(pFunc);
        Py_DECREF(pModule); 
    }
    else {
        PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        return 120;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I omit "import numpy as np" from the Python code, the program runs fine. However, including the line "import numpy as np" gives the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/MyUserName/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/home/MyUserName/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/home/MyUserName/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: /home/MyUserName/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_RecursionError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/MyFolder/EmbedTest.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/MyUserName/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/MyUserName/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.8 from "/home/MyUserName/anaconda3/bin/python3"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.19.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: /home/MyUserName/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyExc_RecursionError

Failed to load "1"
```

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868528/importing-the-numpy-c-extensions-failed) question and tried installing numpy and setup tools, but to no avail. *Please note* that the problem only appears when I try to run Python as embedded C++ code. For example, the following runs without trouble:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

class model:
    def init(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        
def test_method(a,b):
    m = model()
    m.init(a,b)
    print("a: ",a,"b: ",b)
    return (a+b,a-b,a*b)

def list_method(a,b):
    m = model()
    m.init(a,b)
    La = [1,2,3]
    sa = 3
    Lb = [2,3,5,7,11]
    sb = 5
    return (La,sa,Lb,sb)

def main():
    arr = np.array([1,2])
    print("Main method")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My environment is:

*Python 3.8.3

*Numpy 1.19.2

*anaconda3

*Linux Debian 10.5

**EDIT**

Per the suggestion of AMC, here is the list of packages installed with conda, from running `conda list` in the terminal:

```
# packages in environment at /home/MyUserName/anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py38_0  
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
alabaster                 0.7.12                     py_0  
anaconda                  2020.07                  py38_0  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py38_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.12                   py38_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.4                      py_0  
argh                      0.26.2                   py38_0  
asn1crypto                1.3.0                    py38_0  
astroid                   2.4.2                    py38_0  
astropy                   4.0.1.post1      py38h7b6447c_1  
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0  
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0  
autopep8                  1.5.3                      py_0  
babel                     2.8.0                      py_0  
backcall                  0.2.0                      py_0  
backports                 1.0                        py_2  
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.1                      py_0  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py38_2  
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1  
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1  
beautifulsoup4            4.9.1                    py38_0  
bitarray                  1.4.0            py38h7b6447c_0  
bkcharts                  0.2                      py38_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.5                      py_0  
blosc                     1.19.0               hd408876_0  
bokeh                     2.1.1                    py38_0  
boto                      2.49.0                   py38_0  
bottleneck                1.3.2            py38heb32a55_1  
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h7b6447c_1000  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0  
ca-certificates           2020.6.24                     0    anaconda
cairo                     1.14.12              h8948797_3  
certifi                   2020.6.20                py38_0    anaconda
cffi                      1.14.0           py38he30daa8_1  
chardet                   3.0.4                 py38_1003  
click                     7.1.2                      py_0  
cloudpickle               1.5.0                      py_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py38_1  
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0  
conda                     4.8.5                    py38_0    anaconda
conda-build               3.18.11                  py38_0  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
conda-package-handling    1.6.1            py38h7b6447c_0  
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1  
contextlib2               0.6.0.post1                py_0  
cosmotransitions          2.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
cryptography              2.9.2            py38h1ba5d50_0  
curl                      7.71.1               hbc83047_1  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py38_0  
cython                    0.29.21          py38he6710b0_0  
cytoolz                   0.10.1           py38h7b6447c_0  
dask                      2.20.0                     py_0  
dask-core                 2.20.0                     py_0  
dbus                      1.13.16              hb2f20db_0  
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0  
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0  
diff-match-patch          20200713                   py_0  
distributed               2.20.0                   py38_0  
docutils                  0.16                     py38_1  
entrypoints               0.3                      py38_0  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                   py_1001  
expat                     2.2.9                he6710b0_2  
fastcache                 1.1.0            py38h7b6447c_0  
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0  
flake8                    3.8.3                      py_0  
flask                     1.1.2                      py_0  
fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0  
freetype                  2.10.2               h5ab3b9f_0  
fribidi                   1.0.9                h7b6447c_0  
fsspec                    0.7.4                      py_0  
future                    0.18.2                   py38_1  
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                haa9412d_0  
gevent                    20.6.2           py38h7b6447c_0  
glib                      2.65.0               h3eb4bd4_0  
glob2                     0.7                        py_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py38hd5f6e3b_3  
graphite2                 1.3.14               h23475e2_0  
greenlet                  0.4.16           py38h7b6447c_0  
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1  
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb31296c_0  
h5py                      2.10.0           py38h7918eee_0  
harfbuzz                  2.4.0                hca77d97_1  
hdf5                      1.10.4               hb1b8bf9_0  
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0  
html5lib                  1.1                        py_0  
icu                       58.2                 he6710b0_3  
idna                      2.10                       py_0  
imageio                   2.9.0                      py_0  
imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0  
importlib-metadata        1.7.0                    py38_0  
importlib_metadata        1.7.0                         0  
intel-openmp              2020.1                      217  
intervaltree              3.0.2                      py_1  
ipykernel                 5.3.2            py38h5ca1d4c_0  
ipython                   7.16.1           py38h5ca1d4c_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py38_0  
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0  
isort                     4.3.21                   py38_0  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                      py_0  
jbig                      2.1                  hdba287a_0  
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0  
jedi                      0.17.1                   py38_0  
jeepney                   0.4.3                      py_0  
jinja2                    2.11.2                     py_0  
joblib                    0.16.0                     py_0  
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2  
json5                     0.9.5                      py_0  
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py38_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py38_7  
jupyter_client            6.1.6                      py_0  
jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_0  
jupyter_core              4.6.3                    py38_0  
jupyterlab                2.1.5                      py_0  
jupyterlab_server         1.2.0                      py_0  
keyring                   21.2.1                   py38_0  
kiwisolver                1.2.0            py38hfd86e86_0  
krb5                      1.18.2               h173b8e3_0  
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py38h7b6447c_0  
lcms2                     2.11                 h396b838_0  
ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1               h53a641e_7  
libarchive                3.4.2                h62408e4_0  
libcurl                   7.71.1               h20c2e04_1  
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h14c3975_1  
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2  
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
liblief                   0.10.1               he6710b0_0  
libllvm9                  9.0.1                h4a3c616_1  
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0  
libsodium                 1.0.18               h7b6447c_0  
libspatialindex           1.9.3                he6710b0_0  
libssh2                   1.9.0                h1ba5d50_1  
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libtiff                   4.1.0                h2733197_1  
libtool                   2.4.6                h7b6447c_5  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2  
libxcb                    1.14                 h7b6447c_0  
libxml2                   2.9.10               he19cac6_1  
libxslt                   1.1.34               hc22bd24_0  
llvmlite                  0.33.0           py38hc6ec683_1  
locket                    0.2.0                    py38_1  
lxml                      4.5.2            py38hefd8a0e_0  
lz4-c                     1.9.2                he6710b0_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h7b6447c_2  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py38h7b6447c_0  
matplotlib                3.2.2                         0  
matplotlib-base           3.2.2            py38hef1b27d_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py38_1  
mistune                   0.8.4           py38h7b6447c_1000  
mkl                       2020.1                      217  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py38he904b0f_0  
mkl_fft                   1.1.0            py38h23d657b_0  
mkl_random                1.1.1            py38h0573a6f_0  
mock                      4.0.2                      py_0  
more-itertools            8.4.0                      py_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h10f8cd9_1  
mpfr                      4.0.2                hb69a4c5_1  
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py38_0  
msgpack-python            1.0.0            py38hfd86e86_1  
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py38_0  
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py38_0  
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py38_0  
nbformat                  5.0.7                      py_0  
ncurses                   6.2                  he6710b0_1  
networkx                  2.4                        py_1  
nltk                      3.5                        py_0  
nose                      1.3.7                    py38_2  
notebook                  6.0.3                    py38_0  
numba                     0.50.1           py38h0573a6f_1  
numexpr                   2.7.1            py38h423224d_0  
numpy                     1.19.2                   pypi_0    pypi
numpydoc                  1.1.0                      py_0  
olefile                   0.46                       py_0  
openpyxl                  3.0.4                      py_0  
openssl                   1.1.1g               h7b6447c_0    anaconda
packaging                 20.4                       py_0  
pandas                    1.0.5            py38h0573a6f_0  
pandoc                    2.10                          0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py38_1  
pango                     1.45.3               hd140c19_0  
parso                     0.7.0                      py_0  
partd                     1.1.0                      py_0  
patchelf                  0.11                 he6710b0_0  
path                      13.1.0                   py38_0  
path.py                   12.4.0                        0  
pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py38_0  
pathtools                 0.1.2                      py_1  
patsy                     0.5.1                    py38_0  
pcre                      8.44                 he6710b0_0  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py38_0  
pexpect                   4.8.0                    py38_0  
pickleshare               0.7.5                 py38_1000  
pillow                    7.2.0            py38hb39fc2d_0  
pip                       20.1.1                   py38_1  
pixman                    0.40.0               h7b6447c_0  
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py38_0  
pluggy                    0.13.1                   py38_0  
ply                       3.11                     py38_0  
prometheus_client         0.8.0                      py_0  
prompt-toolkit            3.0.5                      py_0  
prompt_toolkit            3.0.5                         0  
psutil                    5.7.0            py38h7b6447c_0  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py38_0  
py                        1.9.0                      py_0  
py-lief                   0.10.1           py38h403a769_0  
pycodestyle               2.6.0                      py_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py38h7b6447c_1  
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2  
pycurl                    7.43.0.5         py38h1ba5d50_0  
pydocstyle                5.0.2                      py_0  
pyflakes                  2.2.0                      py_0  
pygments                  2.6.1                      py_0  
pylint                    2.5.3                    py38_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.30           py38he6710b0_0  
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                     py_1  
pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py38h05f1152_4  
pyrsistent                0.16.0           py38h7b6447c_0  
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py38_0  
pytables                  3.6.1            py38h9fd0a39_0  
pytest                    5.4.3                    py38_0  
python                    3.8.3                hcff3b4d_2  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0  
python-jsonrpc-server     0.3.4                      py_1  
python-language-server    0.34.1                   py38_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.9                        py_0  
pytz                      2020.1                     py_0  
pywavelets                1.1.1            py38h7b6447c_0  
pyxdg                     0.26                       py_0  
pyyaml                    5.3.1            py38h7b6447c_1  
pyzmq                     19.0.1           py38he6710b0_1  
qdarkstyle                2.8.1                      py_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h5867ecd_1  
qtawesome                 0.7.2                      py_0  
qtconsole                 4.7.5                      py_0  
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0  
readline                  8.0                  h7b6447c_0  
regex                     2020.6.8         py38h7b6447c_0  
requests                  2.24.0                     py_0  
ripgrep                   11.0.2               he32d670_0  
rope                      0.17.0                     py_0  
rtree                     0.9.4                    py38_1  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.87          py38h7b6447c_1  
scikit-image              0.16.2           py38h0573a6f_0  
scikit-learn              0.23.1           py38h423224d_0  
scipy                     1.5.0            py38h0b6359f_0  
seaborn                   0.10.1                     py_0  
secretstorage             3.1.2                    py38_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py38_0  
setuptools                50.3.2                   pypi_0    pypi
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py38_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py38_0  
sip                       4.19.13          py38he6710b0_0  
six                       1.15.0                     py_0  
snappy                    1.1.8                he6710b0_0  
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0  
sortedcollections         1.2.1                      py_0  
sortedcontainers          2.2.2                      py_0  
soupsieve                 2.0.1                      py_0  
sphinx                    3.1.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py38_1  
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.4                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.2.3                      py_0  
spyder                    4.1.4                    py38_0  
spyder-kernels            1.9.2                    py38_0  
sqlalchemy                1.3.18           py38h7b6447c_0  
sqlite                    3.32.3               h62c20be_0  
statsmodels               0.11.1           py38h7b6447c_0  
sympy                     1.6.1                    py38_0  
tbb                       2020.0               hfd86e86_0  
tblib                     1.6.0                      py_0  
terminado                 0.8.3                    py38_0  
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0  
threadpoolctl             2.1.0              pyh5ca1d4c_0  
tk                        8.6.10               hbc83047_0  
toml                      0.10.1                     py_0  
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0  
tornado                   6.0.4            py38h7b6447c_1  
tqdm                      4.47.0                     py_0  
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py38_0  
typing_extensions         3.7.4.2                    py_0  
ujson                     1.35             py38h7b6447c_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py38_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h14c3975_0  
urllib3                   1.25.9                     py_0  
watchdog                  0.10.3                   py38_0  
wcwidth                   0.2.5                      py_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py38_1  
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0  
wheel                     0.34.2                   py38_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py38_0  
wrapt                     1.11.2           py38h7b6447c_0  
wurlitzer                 2.0.1                    py38_0  
xlrd                      1.2.0                      py_0  
xlsxwriter                1.2.9                      py_0  
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py38_0  
xmltodict                 0.12.0                     py_0  
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
yaml                      0.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
yapf                      0.30.0                     py_0  
zeromq                    4.3.2                he6710b0_2  
zict                      2.0.0                      py_0  
zipp                      3.1.0                      py_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3  
zope                      1.0                      py38_1  
zope.event                4.4                      py38_0  
zope.interface            4.7.1            py38h7b6447c_0  
zstd                      1.4.5                h0b5b093_0
```

Comment: Can you share the list of packages in the Conda environment? Have you tried creating a new environment?

Comment: @AMC Thank you for your comment, and sorry for the late reply. I have added a copy of the output from conda list to my post. No, I have not tried creating a new environment.

Comment: You're using the base environment for this?

Comment: @AMC Hi again, and sorry for the late reply. Yes, I think it is the base environment. How can I check?

Comment: Are you activating an environment? `sys.executable` might give an indication as to what you're using. More info: [How do I find the name of the conda environment in which my code is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36539623)

Comment: @AMC I added "import sys" and the "print(sys.executable)" to the python file. The output when I run (having to comment out "import numpy as np" in order to do so) is "/home/MyUserName/anaconda3/python3".

Comment: It seems that you're using the base environment, then. Using the base environment for development is generally a bad idea, you should create a new environment for each project/application. You should also consider resetting the base environment (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45838041) or reinstalling Conda.

Comment: @AMC Alright, thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Does the error still occur in a new environment?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.